# How to check whether the index is missing or corrupt in Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I have created an Apache Lucene search project using java.If there is an error/corrupt/missed files in index folder,how can I find it?

I have tried [CheckIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html) but still no good.
How can I check whether the index is damaged or corrupt?

```
public class Test {
    private static final String INDEX_DIR = "/home/amila/Lucene/REST/indexing";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIR));
            CheckIndex checkIndex = new CheckIndex(directory);
            Status status= checkIndex.checkIndex();
            System.out.println(status.missingSegments);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are only checking missing segments, but there can be other potential problems (`validCounter`, `missingSegmentVersion`, etc.) so how about those? Also, what does the `clean` flag say? And finally, do you **know** this is a broken index and trying to test it? You need to provide us more details.

Comment: Yes using clean I managed to full fill my requirement  :)

Comment: You could also call checkIndex.fixIndex(status), which will repair any problems (if they exist)

Comment: Which version of Lucene are you using?